# How can I solve watching issue in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I really hope, you can help me.

When I import a module in the index.js in a following way: ( import Test from './src/test'; ) Webpack recognizes the .web.js extension and uses it. However, if I make changes in the file system for instance I delete or rename this file, the webpack will notice that the file is missing. Nevertheless, it doesn't recompile and doesn't use the other file opportunity (test.js).

I have used webpack 3.6.0 and I tried to use in Watch mode, too. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

[image: Click here for the animated image illustration]

Comment: So the problem is that you can not delete any files, since it throws a compile error? When I look at the error it says index.js is using the renamed file

Comment: If you change folder layout structure, sometimes you just have to restart webpack. Problem solved!

Comment: Can you add your webpack config?

Comment: I configure more extensions types what webpack could use. And it use it when it make first compile. If I work I don't want to restart webpack always. But file system often changes in a development process. Webpack should recompile when file system changes and use given files in imports. If test.web.js exists webpack should use this. If is not exists webpack should use test.js. But unfortunately this does not work that way.

Here is a repo:
[https://github.com/kifli01/webpack-watch](https://github.com/kifli01/webpack-watch)